# Alert dialog default style in Android on appcelerator

Tags: android-alertdialog, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

i'm trying to edit the style of my alert dialog in android. I hate the default style, but i saw on the web there are other default style very beautiful. How can i change it? There isn't a property like iOS Titanium.UI.iPhone.AlertDialogStyle?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use custom theme for dialog.

Comment: with custom theme you mean use a custom view right? Yeah, i used it on some alert dialog but i ask if there are other default theme like iOS :)

Comment: I'm trying to use the androidView property to add a custom view, i have a question: Can i add only the view with my style without any button, and see the other alert item (button, title) on it? Or i need to do all manually? (button, text ecc.)